# How to paint by face using a color palette and UV coordinates

Tags: texturing, uv, add-on

I am painting a low-poly mesh and I want to use a color-palette (that I could switch on the fly by replacing a texture). The workflow I know (as described in [this video](https://youtu.be/4fvf9-pFuWA?i=7kXzoGZHYw6RpzwB&t=405)), is to go to edit mode, select the faces I want to color and move their UV coordinates in the UV editor.

However, I am not quite happy with this process as:

1. It's a bit slow (select the faces, go to the UV panel, scale to zero, move to the right pixel).
2. I do not have feedback on the look of the mesh until I am done selecting the faces.

I would like to have a sort of brush, that when used, set the UV coordinates of each face to a given value (corresponding to a color in my palette). Is there an builtin way to do this, or an add-on that can help?

If no, what would be the best way to create an add-on to do this? I looked at `bpy.types.Operator`, but it seems a bit low-level for this, I was hoping to be able to sub-class Brush or something like this.

Comment: You can write a script that automates the task of scaling down and moving the UV parts of the selected mesh. "Painting" would mean, selecting the mesh parts in *Edit* mode, and then running the script. I have no idea if you can change the behavior of a brush to mimic the process described.

Comment: @Blunder In the end I created an addon that can change the UV of the brushed faces. I'll post it here when it will be done.